# connect PCIe 3.0 ssd to another computer

Tags: ssd, pci-express

I have a Samsung SSD SM951 drive in a dead laptop.  I'd like to connect the drive to another computer.  It's PCIe 3.0

Is there a cable or something I can buy to help connect it to another computer?

Cheers

Comment: There exists M.2 (PCI-E) to SATA3 converters.  If you have properly identified your SSD, something like [this](http://www.amazon.com/ZTC-Enclosure-Board-Adapter-ZTC-EN006/dp/B00SM0M5QC/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1454942042&sr=8-1&keywords=M.2+to+SATA+3+converter) or [this](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00XXPXISK/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pd_S_ttl?_encoding=UTF8&colid=ALLGFUJQ23QF&coliid=I1FEE13NVQCODQ&psc=1) should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current accepted answer is inaccurate and I believe may be referring to the backwards compatibility of Mini SATA, or SATA 3. PCI-e is a very different technology and you will need a different solution to this for it to work.

### Your SSD connector - PCI-E M.2

[image]

### mSATA and SATA

[image]

### Other M.2

[image]

---

You haven't stated whether you are trying to put the device into a laptop or a desktop. If you're trying to put it in another laptop *without* M.2. PCI-e, you may struggle due to lack of space, although adapters do exist. These adapters will allow it to work in a desktop or a laptop though, but make sure the device is designed for PCI-e M.2. rather than SATA M.2.

You can find adapters between these technologies, but make sure you're looking up the correct thing. M.2 is especially confusing as it could use PCI-e *or* SATA protocol.

Comment: Ahhh.. thanks.  That makes more sense. I looked a the adapter you suggested, but I think it requires a SATA interface. "Plugging any mini PCI-e (SATA interface) SSD module into this kit, it turns into a standard 2.5 Inch SATA SSD."  Looking at the SSD I have, it is PCIe 3.0 interface
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820147425

Comment: @Blaze Yes, you're quite right. What are you looking to connect the drive to, another laptop or a desktop?

Comment: A desktop.. Do you think I could plug this into the desktop http://www.amazon.com/Lycom-DT-120-PCIe-Adapter-Support/dp/B00MYCQP38/ref=pd_bxgy_147_img_3?ie=UTF8&refRID=1J3X1YAPEZ5RT9NFN7XP  And then plug the SSD PCIe 3.0 into it?

Comment: @Blaze Aha, if it's for a desktop, then yes you have a lot more option to get it working. What you've linked looks exactly like what you'd need, yes :)