# PCIe SSD on USB

Tags: usb, ssd, pci-express, nvme

I have a PCIe NVMe SSD, the [Samsung PM951](https://www.cnet.com/products/samsung-pm951-mzvlv256hchp-solid-state-drive-256-gb-pci-express-3-0-x4-nvme/specs/), taken from a Lenovo Ideapad 700-15ISK, which is dead, for data recovery. So far I've not been able to find a way to connect this SSD to another PC externally.

Is it possible to connect a PCIe NVMe SSD to a computer Externally? Unfortunately I don't own a desktop PC so the solution offered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1036874/connect-pcie-3-0-ssd-to-another-computer) is not applicable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, a USB Mass Storage or USB Attached SCSI adapter would be possible of course, though with severely limited performance.

<s>That being said, although announced, no such thing is available right now. That means you need to deal with PCIe directly.</s> Scratch that, there actually are enclosures like that now. Quality and speed seem to be limited for now though.

There’s another solution: Thunderbolt. Enclosures exist, though availability is still a problem. Some are rather pricey, too.

If you do not have a PC with Thunderbolt connectivity, you can also just buy a PCIe-to-M.2 adapter card. These fit in a regular PC’s PCIe slots. They’re almost completely passive and as such very cheap.

Comment: The performance is no issue as it data recovery at this point. I have seen the PCIe M.2 Adapter cards but since I don't have acces to a PC with PCIe slots, that is not an option right now.

Comment: Also I currently have the Transcend M.2 SSD Enclosure Kit but that seems to be only compatible with SATA-600 SSD's not the PCIe NVMe SSD's.

Comment: Yes, you need to take extra care to when selecting an adapter. “NVMe USB enclosure” appears to be a good search term.

Answer (score -1):

This is no real Problem...you only need a m.2 to usb adapter... the cost about 20bucks though...

for example this one on amazon:

[https://www.amazon.de/CSL-Festplattengehäuse-Festplatten-Schnittstellen-Standard-Unterstützung/dp/B071W35YBS/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1540824605&sr=8-3&keywords=m.2+to+usb](https://www.amazon.de/CSL-Festplattengeh%C3%A4use-Festplatten-Schnittstellen-Standard-Unterst%C3%BCtzung/dp/B071W35YBS/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1540824605&sr=8-3&keywords=m.2+to+usb)

Comment: This is unfortunately not compatible with the PCIe NVMe SSD I have. "NICHT KOMPATIBEL mit PCIe"